# SQL Server : issue with query

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with my query:

```
SELECT Firma, Czas, Dzien, Opis, Kto, ID
FROM Rok2016
WHERE (Dzien BETWEEN @z1 AND @z2) 
  AND (Firma = @x) 
  AND (Kto = @y)
```

I have to modify it so when I put `*` in the `@x` parameter, it is supposed to show data of all records between `@z1` and `@z2` dates

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you want the `Firma = @x` predicate to be optional?

Comment: ...without looking at `@y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you want.

```
SELECT  Firma, Czas, Dzien, Opis, Kto, ID
FROM    Rok2016
WHERE   (Dzien BETWEEN @z1 AND @z2) 
AND ((@x='*' AND Firma!='')OR(@x!='*' AND Firma=@x))
AND (Kto = @y)
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Modified based on your query

```
SELECT
    Firma, Czas, Dzien, Opis,   Kto, ID
FROM
    Rok2016
WHERE
    ((Dzien BETWEEN @z1 AND @z2) AND (Firma = @x) AND (Kto = @y) AND (@x != '*')) 
OR
  ((Dzien BETWEEN @z1 AND @z2) AND (Firma = @x) AND (@x = '*'))
```

If `@x` is not equal to `*` it would run your original query.

Otherwise if you put `*` in `@x`, it shows data to all records between `@z1` and `@z2` dates, without checking `Kto = @y`

Answer (score 0):

Although you could modify this query to have something like `... (((Firma = @x) AND (Kto = @y)) OR @x = '*')` that approach could cause problems with getting an optimal query plan for your query. For more detail, see
http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic

I would recommend writing two different queries, one for `(Firma = @x) AND (Kto = @y)` and another which has no filter on `Firma` or `Kto` and then have your application choose which query to execute based on the value of `@x`.